# Default display pattern changes colour

Tags: support, profile-page

I have not added any profile photo . Originaly the color was something else and now it has turned pink . I didnt change it and I dont know whether one can change it . I was under the impression that its system generated and will remain so till I change it .

Why did the colour of my profile picture change all of a sudden ?

Comment: I don't know, but I have a feeling you should post this to meta.SE.

Comment: @MARamezani What colour do you see right now ?

Comment: I can elaborate more later, but this is most likely due to a change in your email address in the system.  When you don't specify an avatar, the system hashes your email to generate the image.

Comment: @jonsca I think that might be the reason

Comment: @MARamezani Okay. Thanks.

Comment: @jonsca How does hashing the email address give an image? Google told me that hashing converts it into a hexadecimal string. Then how does the string become an image?

Comment: @pikachu This is a good explanation of it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17443/how-is-the-default-user-avatar-generated